# Add VM Minions to existing Kubernetes Master

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I have a master node running on GCE, I would like to add a new node. I created a new VM on Ubuntu OS on GCE.

I tired many things but unable to add the new VM to the cluster. I  know that we can scale using the GCE Template instances. But I want to know if there is any way we can add a new Vm to cluster and run that up.

Ideally the question would be if I can add a new Minion( bare metal, VM...) to a existing cluster (on GCE, AWS etc.,), if so how. I tired looking for boostrap scripts but unable to get kubelet, kube-proxy up on the minion.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With kubeadm I believe that it is possible

Comment: I did tried with kubeadm the nodes are being connected by  the kube-DNS and 'flannel' are not not running,

Comment: I tried use `weave` instead of `flannel` for the pod network and it was working as expected.  Would there be any difference in terms of performance ?